# query with a subquery that returns thousands of results takes multiple seconds to execute

Tags: postgresql

I'm collecting conversations about stocks from Reddit. The following is what it looks like in my postgres

```
create table stock
        (
            code               varchar(10) not null
                constraint "PK_c73240b87ebf65d15337579f9fd"
                    primary key,
            confirmed          boolean,
            "confirmationTime" timestamp
        );

        create table conversation
        (
            id           varchar(100)           not null
                constraint "PK_864528ec4274360a40f66c29845"
                    primary key,
            "createdUtc" timestamp              not null,
            type         conversation_type_enum not null,
            votes        integer                not null,
            text         varchar                not null,
            source       varchar                not null,
            "sourceUrl"  varchar                not null,
            "parentId"   varchar(100)
                constraint "FK_58aa115ae3e7e7c6f79ad38d0c0"
                    references conversation
                    on delete cascade
        );

        create table conversation_stocks_stock
        (
            "conversationId" varchar(100) not null
                constraint "FK_f78b7bf984f96648653812c5500"
                    references conversation
                    on update cascade on delete cascade,
            "stockCode"      varchar(10)  not null
                constraint "FK_927e043874ad9469e451671a530"
                    references stock
                    on update cascade on delete cascade,
            constraint "PK_5478028d1f4bf3c91dc0da2849d"
                primary key ("conversationId", "stockCode")
        );

        create index "IDX_f78b7bf984f96648653812c550"
            on conversation_stocks_stock ("conversationId");

        create index "IDX_927e043874ad9469e451671a53"
            on conversation_stocks_stock ("stockCode");

        create index conversationCreatedUtc on conversation ("createdUtc");
```

Until recently I was calculating how much people are interested in a certain stock during a certain time in the following way

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_stock_interest(stock varchar, start_time timestamp, end_time timestamp) RETURNS integer AS $$
      BEGIN
          RETURN
              (with recursive convo AS (
                  select id, votes, "parentId", "createdUtc" from conversation
                                                                      join conversation_stocks_stock css on css."conversationId" = id
                  where css."stockCode" = stock
                    and "createdUtc" > start_time and "createdUtc" <= end_time
                  union
                  select thread.id, thread.votes, thread."parentId", thread."createdUtc" from conversation thread
                                                                                                  join convo com on thread."parentId" = com.id
                  where thread."createdUtc" > start_time and thread."createdUtc" <= end_time
              ) select COALESCE((count(*) + sum(convo.votes)), 0) from convo left join conversation_stocks_stock css on convo.id = css."conversationId");
      END
      $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
          LEAKPROOF
          STRICT
          PARALLEL SAFE;
```

This spits out a result in less than 100ms, however I noticed it produces a wrong result. Assuming a thread that was written on 2023-01-03 and a comment under this thread that was written on 2023-01-05, If I try to do `select calculate_stock_interest('AAA', '2023-01-02', '2023-01-04')`, the function will return 2, as expected, however for `select calculate_stock_interest('AAA', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-06')` it will return 0. This is because the recursion will see that the thread is outside of the requested time span and will not traverse the child comments.

So i fixed the problem by re-writing the function in the following way

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_stock_interest(stock varchar, start_time timestamp, end_time timestamp) RETURNS integer AS $$
        BEGIN
            RETURN
                (with recursive convo AS (
                    select id, votes, "parentId", "createdUtc" from conversation
                                                                        join conversation_stocks_stock css on css."conversationId" = id
                    where css."stockCode" = stock
                    union
                    select thread.id, thread.votes, thread."parentId", thread."createdUtc" from conversation thread
                    join convo com on thread."parentId" = com.id
                ) select
                      COALESCE((count(*) + sum(convo.votes)), 0)
                  from convo
                  left join conversation_stocks_stock css on convo.id = css."conversationId"
                  where "createdUtc" > start_time and "createdUtc" <= end_time);
        END
        $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
            LEAKPROOF
            STRICT
            PARALLEL SAFE;
```

Now I get the right result, but... the subquery no longer hits the `conversationCreatedUtc`. It produces thousands of results and the function overall takes multiple seconds to run... and I need to execute the function thousands of times...

Any hints on how to improve the performance here?

**Edit**

The following query

```
explain with recursive convo AS (
    select id, votes, "parentId", "createdUtc" from conversation
                                                        join conversation_stocks_stock css on css."conversationId" = id
    where css."stockCode" = 'AAA'
    union
    select thread.id, thread.votes, thread."parentId", thread."createdUtc" from conversation thread
                                                                                    join convo com on thread."parentId" = com.id
) select
            COALESCE((count(*) + sum(convo.votes)), 0)
        from convo
                 left join conversation_stocks_stock css on convo.id = css."conversationId"
        where "createdUtc" > '2022-01-01' and "createdUtc" <= '2022-02-01'
```

gives me

```
Aggregate  (cost=184925.75..184925.76 rows=1 width=8)
  CTE convo
    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=4.82..184275.09 rows=7753 width=26)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.82..161.30 rows=13 width=26)
                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on conversation_stocks_stock css_1  (cost=4.40..51.58 rows=13 width=7)
"                      Recheck Cond: ((""stockCode"")::text = 'AAA'::text)"
"                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""IDX_927e043874ad9469e451671a53""  (cost=0.00..4.39 rows=13 width=0)"
"                            Index Cond: ((""stockCode"")::text = 'AAA'::text)"
"                ->  Index Scan using ""PK_864528ec4274360a40f66c29845"" on conversation  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=26)"
"                      Index Cond: ((id)::text = (css_1.""conversationId"")::text)"
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.23..18395.87 rows=774 width=26)
"                Hash Cond: ((thread.""parentId"")::text = (com.id)::text)"
                ->  Seq Scan on conversation thread  (cost=0.00..17345.66 rows=276866 width=26)
                ->  Hash  (cost=2.60..2.60 rows=130 width=218)
                      ->  WorkTable Scan on convo com  (cost=0.00..2.60 rows=130 width=218)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..649.57 rows=219 width=4)
        ->  CTE Scan on convo  (cost=0.00..193.83 rows=39 width=222)
"              Filter: ((""createdUtc"" > '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (""createdUtc"" <= '2022-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using ""IDX_f78b7bf984f96648653812c550"" on conversation_stocks_stock css  (cost=0.29..11.63 rows=6 width=7)"
"              Index Cond: (""conversationId"" = (convo.id)::text)"
JIT:
  Functions: 24
"  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
```

and `analyze verbose` spit out the following:

```
analyze verbose
analyzing "public.migrations"
"migrations": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 4 live rows and 0 dead rows; 4 rows in sample, 4 estimated total rows
analyzing "public.conversation"
"conversation": scanned 14577 of 14577 pages, containing 276866 live rows and 2161 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 276866 estimated total rows
analyzing "public.conversation_stocks_stock"
"conversation_stocks_stock": scanned 799 of 799 pages, containing 147195 live rows and 727 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 147195 estimated total rows
analyzing "public.stock"
"stock": scanned 91 of 91 pages, containing 12778 live rows and 4 dead rows; 12778 rows in sample, 12778 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_type"
"pg_type": scanned 15 of 15 pages, containing 613 live rows and 28 dead rows; 613 rows in sample, 613 estimated total rows
analyzing "public.stock_interest"
"stock_interest": scanned 280 of 280 pages, containing 43897 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 43897 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_table"
"pg_foreign_table": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_authid"
"pg_authid": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 12 live rows and 0 dead rows; 12 rows in sample, 12 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_statistic_ext_data"
"pg_statistic_ext_data": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_user_mapping"
"pg_user_mapping": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_subscription"
"pg_subscription": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_attribute"
"pg_attribute": scanned 57 of 57 pages, containing 3059 live rows and 143 dead rows; 3059 rows in sample, 3059 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_proc"
"pg_proc": scanned 94 of 94 pages, containing 3204 live rows and 4 dead rows; 3204 rows in sample, 3204 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_class"
"pg_class": scanned 13 of 13 pages, containing 413 live rows and 33 dead rows; 413 rows in sample, 413 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_attrdef"
"pg_attrdef": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 1 live rows and 0 dead rows; 1 rows in sample, 1 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_constraint"
"pg_constraint": scanned 3 of 3 pages, containing 114 live rows and 0 dead rows; 114 rows in sample, 114 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_inherits"
"pg_inherits": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_index"
"pg_index": scanned 4 of 4 pages, containing 164 live rows and 8 dead rows; 164 rows in sample, 164 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_operator"
"pg_operator": scanned 14 of 14 pages, containing 804 live rows and 0 dead rows; 804 rows in sample, 804 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_opfamily"
"pg_opfamily": scanned 2 of 2 pages, containing 146 live rows and 0 dead rows; 146 rows in sample, 146 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_opclass"
"pg_opclass": scanned 3 of 3 pages, containing 177 live rows and 0 dead rows; 177 rows in sample, 177 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_am"
"pg_am": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 7 live rows and 0 dead rows; 7 rows in sample, 7 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_amop"
"pg_amop": scanned 7 of 7 pages, containing 945 live rows and 0 dead rows; 945 rows in sample, 945 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_amproc"
"pg_amproc": scanned 5 of 5 pages, containing 697 live rows and 0 dead rows; 697 rows in sample, 697 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_language"
"pg_language": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 4 live rows and 0 dead rows; 4 rows in sample, 4 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata"
"pg_largeobject_metadata": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_aggregate"
"pg_aggregate": scanned 2 of 2 pages, containing 145 live rows and 0 dead rows; 145 rows in sample, 145 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_statistic_ext"
"pg_statistic_ext": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_rewrite"
"pg_rewrite": scanned 13 of 13 pages, containing 140 live rows and 5 dead rows; 140 rows in sample, 140 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_trigger"
"pg_trigger": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 12 live rows and 0 dead rows; 12 rows in sample, 12 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_event_trigger"
"pg_event_trigger": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_description"
"pg_description": scanned 44 of 44 pages, containing 5099 live rows and 0 dead rows; 5099 rows in sample, 5099 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_cast"
"pg_cast": scanned 2 of 2 pages, containing 230 live rows and 0 dead rows; 230 rows in sample, 230 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_enum"
"pg_enum": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 2 live rows and 0 dead rows; 2 rows in sample, 2 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_namespace"
"pg_namespace": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 4 live rows and 0 dead rows; 4 rows in sample, 4 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_conversion"
"pg_conversion": scanned 2 of 2 pages, containing 128 live rows and 0 dead rows; 128 rows in sample, 128 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_depend"
"pg_depend": scanned 66 of 66 pages, containing 8884 live rows and 140 dead rows; 8884 rows in sample, 8884 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_database"
"pg_database": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 4 live rows and 0 dead rows; 4 rows in sample, 4 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_db_role_setting"
"pg_db_role_setting": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_tablespace"
"pg_tablespace": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 2 live rows and 0 dead rows; 2 rows in sample, 2 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_auth_members"
"pg_auth_members": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 3 live rows and 0 dead rows; 3 rows in sample, 3 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_shdepend"
"pg_shdepend": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 12 live rows and 0 dead rows; 12 rows in sample, 12 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_shdescription"
"pg_shdescription": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 3 live rows and 0 dead rows; 3 rows in sample, 3 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_config"
"pg_ts_config": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 29 live rows and 0 dead rows; 29 rows in sample, 29 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_config_map"
"pg_ts_config_map": scanned 3 of 3 pages, containing 551 live rows and 0 dead rows; 551 rows in sample, 551 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_dict"
"pg_ts_dict": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 29 live rows and 0 dead rows; 29 rows in sample, 29 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_parser"
"pg_ts_parser": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 1 live rows and 0 dead rows; 1 rows in sample, 1 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_ts_template"
"pg_ts_template": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 5 live rows and 0 dead rows; 5 rows in sample, 5 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_extension"
"pg_extension": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 1 live rows and 0 dead rows; 1 rows in sample, 1 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_data_wrapper"
"pg_foreign_data_wrapper": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_foreign_server"
"pg_foreign_server": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_policy"
"pg_policy": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_replication_origin"
"pg_replication_origin": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_default_acl"
"pg_default_acl": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_init_privs"
"pg_init_privs": scanned 3 of 3 pages, containing 199 live rows and 0 dead rows; 199 rows in sample, 199 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_seclabel"
"pg_seclabel": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_shseclabel"
"pg_shseclabel": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_collation"
"pg_collation": scanned 26 of 26 pages, containing 810 live rows and 0 dead rows; 810 rows in sample, 810 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_partitioned_table"
"pg_partitioned_table": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_range"
"pg_range": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 6 live rows and 0 dead rows; 6 rows in sample, 6 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_transform"
"pg_transform": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_sequence"
"pg_sequence": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 1 live rows and 1 dead rows; 1 rows in sample, 1 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_publication"
"pg_publication": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_publication_rel"
"pg_publication_rel": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel"
"pg_subscription_rel": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "pg_catalog.pg_largeobject"
"pg_largeobject": scanned 0 of 0 pages, containing 0 live rows and 0 dead rows; 0 rows in sample, 0 estimated total rows
analyzing "information_schema.sql_parts"
"sql_parts": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 10 live rows and 0 dead rows; 10 rows in sample, 10 estimated total rows
analyzing "information_schema.sql_implementation_info"
"sql_implementation_info": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 12 live rows and 0 dead rows; 12 rows in sample, 12 estimated total rows
analyzing "information_schema.sql_features"
"sql_features": scanned 8 of 8 pages, containing 713 live rows and 0 dead rows; 713 rows in sample, 713 estimated total rows
analyzing "information_schema.sql_sizing"
"sql_sizing": scanned 1 of 1 pages, containing 23 live rows and 0 dead rows; 23 rows in sample, 23 estimated total rows
[2023-01-09 16:43:34] completed in 529 ms
```

EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) spits out the following:

```
Aggregate  (cost=184942.19..184942.20 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=545.520..545.524 rows=1 loops=1)
"  Output: COALESCE((count(*) + sum(convo.votes)), '0'::bigint)"
  Buffers: shared hit=107922 read=9064
  CTE convo
    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=4.82..184276.59 rows=7803 width=26) (actual time=22.848..545.265 rows=383 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=107922 read=9064
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.82..161.30 rows=13 width=26) (actual time=22.845..23.245 rows=80 loops=1)
"                Output: conversation.id, conversation.votes, conversation.""parentId"", conversation.""createdUtc"""
                Inner Unique: true
                Buffers: shared hit=370
                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.conversation_stocks_stock css_1  (cost=4.40..51.58 rows=13 width=7) (actual time=0.035..0.100 rows=80 loops=1)
"                      Output: css_1.""conversationId"", css_1.""stockCode"""
"                      Recheck Cond: ((css_1.""stockCode"")::text = 'AAA'::text)"
                      Heap Blocks: exact=48
                      Buffers: shared hit=50
"                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""IDX_927e043874ad9469e451671a53""  (cost=0.00..4.39 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=80 loops=1)"
"                            Index Cond: ((css_1.""stockCode"")::text = 'AAA'::text)"
                            Buffers: shared hit=2
"                ->  Index Scan using ""PK_864528ec4274360a40f66c29845"" on public.conversation  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=80)"
"                      Output: conversation.id, conversation.""createdUtc"", conversation.type, conversation.votes, conversation.text, conversation.source, conversation.""sourceUrl"", conversation.""parentId"""
"                      Index Cond: ((conversation.id)::text = (css_1.""conversationId"")::text)"
                      Buffers: shared hit=320
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.23..18395.92 rows=779 width=26) (actual time=8.887..65.172 rows=41 loops=8)
"                Output: thread.id, thread.votes, thread.""parentId"", thread.""createdUtc"""
"                Hash Cond: ((thread.""parentId"")::text = (com.id)::text)"
                Buffers: shared hit=107552 read=9064
                ->  Seq Scan on public.conversation thread  (cost=0.00..17345.66 rows=276866 width=26) (actual time=0.002..28.900 rows=276866 loops=8)
"                      Output: thread.id, thread.""createdUtc"", thread.type, thread.votes, thread.text, thread.source, thread.""sourceUrl"", thread.""parentId"""
                      Buffers: shared hit=107552 read=9064
                ->  Hash  (cost=2.60..2.60 rows=130 width=218) (actual time=0.109..0.109 rows=48 loops=8)
                      Output: com.id
                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 14kB
                      ->  WorkTable Scan on convo com  (cost=0.00..2.60 rows=130 width=218) (actual time=0.086..0.090 rows=48 loops=8)
                            Output: com.id
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..664.49 rows=223 width=4) (actual time=545.489..545.490 rows=0 loops=1)
        Output: convo.votes
        Buffers: shared hit=107922 read=9064
        ->  CTE Scan on convo  (cost=0.00..195.08 rows=39 width=222) (actual time=545.488..545.489 rows=0 loops=1)
"              Output: convo.id, convo.votes, convo.""parentId"", convo.""createdUtc"""
"              Filter: ((convo.""createdUtc"" > '2022-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (convo.""createdUtc"" <= '2022-02-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
              Rows Removed by Filter: 383
              Buffers: shared hit=107922 read=9064
"        ->  Index Only Scan using ""IDX_f78b7bf984f96648653812c550"" on public.conversation_stocks_stock css  (cost=0.29..11.98 rows=6 width=7) (never executed)"
"              Output: css.""conversationId"""
"              Index Cond: (css.""conversationId"" = (convo.id)::text)"
              Heap Fetches: 0
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=43
Planning Time: 0.963 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 27
"  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 2.297 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 1.153 ms, Emission 22.291 ms, Total 25.740 ms"
Execution Time: 548.467 ms
```

Comment: Post the explain plan for the queries inside the functions. Follow the instructions at https://explain.depesz.com/ . Post the explain plan output as an EDIT to your post and include a link to Depesz graphical output.

Comment: Was the table analyzed between executions?

Comment: Could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for the statements? In plain text, and including the inner SELECT statements from the function

Comment: added the "explain" now. I'm not quite sure how to "analyze" it though

Comment: analyzed what i could o_o

Comment: `stock_interest` that you may find in there is a materialized view that invokes the stored function a few hundred thousands of times

Comment: Frank was suggesting to generate the plan using `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) select ....` so that the query is actually run and we can see which part is slow.

Comment: oh. I guess i haven't seen this thing parametrised like this before. updated now

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/s/RwuB graphical explain plan. The planner is doing a sequence scan instead of an index scan because it thinks it will have to return many rows and the seq scan is more efficient. Run `ANALYZE` on the `conversation` table if you have not done that lately. Move this into your CTE so the CTE is only working on rows in the expected date range `where "createdUtc" > start_time and "createdUtc" <= end_time)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index on conversation."parentId".

Comment: Doesn't the FK constraint automatically create an index?

Comment: No, Postgres does not automatically create an index on the FK. It only creates an index on the PK and any Unique keys defined, both of which may be the target of a FK.

Comment: wow... i also thought the index on fk was created automatically... but you're right! Adding this index speeds it up by 10x! o_o nice! thank you